# Jquery Cycle plugin scrolling trough the thumbs

Tags: jquery, scroll, thumbnails

I am busy with a nice slider for videos and everything is going well but now i am stuck on the thumbnail navigation...

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wnVn/

When you use the thumbnail arrows then that is not working. How can i make that work? And that the thumbs scroll with the video slider when you scroll trough them.

(i hope you guys are understeanding what i am meaning)

Thnx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7wnVn/5/

your callbacks have some error, so i deleted them

Comment: you have 5 items. your navigation container is narrow, so 5th element wrap to the next string. look: http://jsfiddle.net/7wnVn/8/

Comment: and add by default class 'active' to the first navigation element. so when user loads the page, first element become active.

Comment: ahhh now i understand what you want :)

Comment: so the easy solution is to use jcarousel for navigation items. cycle cant do this. or write your own small 'carousel' for navigation.